# Scroll effect for click on menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a menu for a single page! Each item on the menu, on click, i want to make de window scroll to the right section of the page!

The menu code

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#me">Me</a></li>
<li><a href="#work">Me</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

On page i have sections like

```
<section id="me"></section>
<section id="work"></section>
```

I've tried myself to write the jQuery function which should do the trick but i had no luck.

```
$(function() {
        $("nav a").click(function(){
            var $place = $(this).attr("href");

                        $(window).animate(
                        {scrollTop: $place.offset().top},400);

            });
    });
```

I'm still at the begining with jQuery so, please, don't throw rocks at me:D

Comment: You could easily do this with HTML itself. Are you particular about using jQuery?

Comment: I just want an effect for the scrolling:D I know it can be done without jQuery..but i don't like how it "jumps"!

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood then. Sorry :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this, please try :

```
 $("body").animate({scrollTop:$($place).offset().top},400);
 e.preventDefault();
```

Edited : you need to prevent default behavior if you don't want direct jumps.